# python Class name not define

Tags: python

this is the model.pythis is the model.py
this is the model.pythis is the model.py

'''

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
```

## Create your models here.

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
USER = (
('1', 'HOD'),
('2', 'STAFF'),
('3', 'STUDENT'),
)
user_type = models.CharField(choices=USER, max_length=50, default=1)
profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/profile_pic')

```
 # Create Course and session Model

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Session_Year(models.Model):
    session_start = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    session_end = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.session_start + " To " + self.session_end
```

'''
this is my admin
'''
#admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


# Register your models here.
class UserModel(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ['username','user_type']

admin.site.register(CustomUser,UserModel)


admin.site.register(Course)
# admin.site.register(Session_Year)
```

'''

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please format your post correctly.  Please also check that your indents are properly done.  While trying to format your post, I noticed both ```Course``` and ```Session_Year``` were classes defined *inside* the ```CustomUser``` class. Was that intentional?

Comment: i just follow whats on youtube please do help

Comment: Please edit your post to fix the formatting.  I don't think your model.py is indented properly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you didn't import Course model in admin.py

Before using it, you must import it to use.

e.g.

```
# course/models.py
class Course(models.Model):
...

# app/admin.py
from course.models import Course

...

admin.site.register(Course)
```

Comment: what does it mean?

it says No module name 'course'  
?

Comment: it's an example. replace `course` part to app name what you named.
If you create app using `startapp` command, you'd already typed it or you can check project layout. Folder name that has Course model is app name.

Comment: And also [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/) is tutorial page for django. Following this page's instruction would be better than watching youtube video.